# What is dielectric constant of metal?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

I'm a graduate student in Chemical engineering. I'm currently calculating formation energy of several metals and I'm encountered with multi-pole correction function. So I need the dielectric constant of metal as input. I know that static dielectric constant of vacuum is a unity and there are several values of various well-known materials. However, I cannot find a dielectric constant table of metals. I do not know if this is a reliable reference, but there was a dielectric constant table that showed negative values.

Where can I find information about dielectric constant of metal? Is there any good book for understanding dielectric constant of metal?

edit:
It seems like I have to clarify little more. I'm sorry for confusing you. I want to calculate Multipole correction function for charged defect of pure metal(e.g. Aluminium) using Markov and Payne(MP) method. I need static dielectric constant for equation in (17) in [Makov, Ge, and M. C. Payne. "Periodic boundary conditions in ab initio calculations." Physical Review B 51.7 (1995): 4014.].

Comment: The dielectric constant is related to electric susceptibility. This is a measure of how polarizable the metal is. So start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility. You might find more in solid state text books.

Comment: For clarity, are you looking for DC values for use in electrostatics, or frequency-dependent curves? If the latter, in what frequency range? In either case, for what metals?

Comment: As one starting point, you can try e.g. https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Au&page=Johnson. Is that what you were looking for? If not, why not?

Comment: The dielectric constant of metals is infinity if you are talking about polarizability as 'most' metals are good conductors.

Comment: @YashasSamaga ... in the DC domain. With AC fields it's a perfectly reasonable (though complex-valued) quantity.

Comment: I don't think he is talking about AC fields because he said "Is there any good book for understanding dielectric constant of metal?". Yeah, I made an assumption. The OP has to clarify it.

Comment: @YashasSamaga Agreed, hence the question above. Either way, Ji woong Yu, you should provide as much context as possible - what are you calculating, using what methods, and why you think you need which precise quantities, noting that things like the DC permittivity of metals might not actually exist.

Comment: It seems like I have to clarify little more. I'm sorry for confusing you. I want to calculate Multipole correction function for charged defect of pure metal(e.g. Aluminium) using Markov and Payne(MP) method. I need static dielectric constant for equation in (17) in [Makov, Ge, and M. C. Payne. "Periodic boundary conditions in ab initio calculations." Physical Review B 51.7 (1995): 4014.].

Comment: Remember the formula for dielectric constant of a dielectric. We relate from the external electric field to the net electric field produces within the dielectric. We also know that the electrostatic field lines in a conductor is zero. I think you can proceed from here.